# Add FilterChips programmatically in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-chips

I am trying to make a Chip Selection which will have multiple choices. In my case I will have choices dynamically so I will have to create chips dynamically. I was successfully able to create it dynamically. But as multi selection needs a property called `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter"`
I am able to pass this in XML but not in kotlin code.
I tried to do like this but didn't succeed:

```
val chip = Chip(chapManager.context, null, android.widget.Filter)
```

It says: `Classifier 'Filter' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here`

Everything else works fine, just I'm not able to pass style to my chip.

Comment: For **AndroidX** https://github.com/karanatwal/MaterialChipsInput

Answer (score 1):

You can define separate layout for `Chip` and setting all the attributes you want in `XML`, then inflate the layout.

```
 val chip = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.chip_layout, view!!.parent.parent as ViewGroup, false) as Chip
```

**chip_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.chip.Chip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/chipTextAppearance"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```